# Detecting Duplicates in a Google Sheet with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I'm trying to build a Google Sheet that looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
|Email              |Duplicate? |
+-------------------+-----------+
|banana@example.com |No         |
|orange@example.com |No         |
|peach@example.com  |No         |
|banana@example.com |Yes        |
|banana@example.com |Yes        |
|apple@example.com  |No         |
|peach@example.com  |Yes        |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

In my example, the first column is filled in manually with some email addresses. The second column should be a formula that returns `Yes` if the value has been duplicated *previously* in the column, and `No` if it hasn't.

So far, I've trying to use `VLOOKUP` and `INDIRECT` inside of `ARRAYFORMULA` to accomplish this. If I can get that to successfully return a value, then I can build the `IF` around it to return the strings I want. However, this doesn't work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, INDIRECT("B1:B" & ROW(B2:B) - 1), 1, FALSE))
```

I've also tried using `COUNTIF`, but that doesn't seem to be playing nice with `ARRAYFORMULA` either.

I'd really appreciate some insight here on what I'm missing. Am I thinking about `ARRAYFORMULA` wrong? Does `INDIRECT` not work the way I think it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", IF(
 (COUNTIFS(A1:A, A1:A, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))>1)*
 (COUNTIF( A1:A, A1:A)>1), "yes", "no"), ))
```

[image]

Comment: That's really cool! Could you explain a little more about how it works and why you went this direction instead of using `INDIRECT`?

Comment: first countifs deals with "previous" duplicates and the 2nd countif checks for any duplicates. then these two counties are multiplied (because AND formula is not supported in arrayformula). not rly sure whats the idea behind indirect tho